# python string to hex representative length value

Tags: python

simple problem I am failing on. Have got a string and I need to find the hex encoded value for the length on it. The following is correct (and working):

```
sample="MyTest1234"
print repr(chr(len(sample)))
```

The output is:
    `'\n'`

However, of course as soon as my "sample" is > 255:

```
sample="MyTest1234"*26
print repr(chr(len(sample)))
```

it fails with:
`ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)`

How would it look like if I want to calculate the length of a string that is bigger than 256?

Comment: Why are you using `chr` at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a built-in function to convert a number to hex, it's called [`hex()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex). Here's your two strings as examples:

```
>>> sample="MyTest1234"
>>> print hex(len(sample))
0xa
>>> sample="MyTest1234"*26
>>> print hex(len(sample))
0x104
```

If you don't want the `0x` prefix, you need to slice it off:

```
>>> print hex(len(sample))[2:]
a
```

Comment: +1 Half a dozen of one, or six of the other. I just figured the OP probably didn't want the `0x` prefix

Comment: taken, thanks a lot - I'll deal with the 0x, that's fine, was more missing the "general point" ;)

Comment: `format()` is perfectly valid, it depends on the output format you want. `hex()` produces valid Python hex literals, `format()` gives you more flexibility over the output (0-padding, uppercase or lowercase, optional standard prefix, etc).

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
sample="MyTest1234"
print format(len(sample), 'x')
# a

sample="MyTest1234"*26
print format(len(sample), 'x')
# 104
```